# Fortran warning at compile time, read error at execution

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to build a meteorological model in a Linux cluster (Ubuntu 12.04) using Intel fortran compiler version 14.0.1. But when trying to compile fdgrib2 module I get this warning message:

```
/opt/intel/bin/ifort -c  -I. /usr/local/rams60/src/pre/fdgrib2/grib_get.f90
/usr/local/rams60/src/pre/fdgrib2/grib_get.f90(209): warning #8042: This argument must be of type character of length 1.   [TOKENS]
   print*,'5--'//trim(tokens(1)), len_trim(tokens(1)),ichar(tokens(1))
------------------------------------------------------------^
ar rs fdgrib2.a grib_get.o
rm -f grib_get.o
```

tokens declaration

> character(len=20) :: tokens(100)

Despite this warning the fdgrib2 executable is built but when trying to run stops with another error message:

```
/usr/local/rams60/build/fdgrib2$ ./fdgrib2 -f DGRIB_IN2
 num args:           2
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
 GRIB to GDF converter
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 Namelist file name: DGRIB_IN2
 GRIB file name    : ./gfs.t00z.pgrbf06.grib2
 WGRIB exec        :
       Assumimg GRIB 2   : /usr/local/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2
 Data date/time    : 99999999  
 Forecast hour     : 99999999  
 3D variables: UGRD      VGRD      TMP       HGT       RH        
 2D variables:


forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
fdgrib2            08076240  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fdgrib2            08074C94  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fdgrib2            08057847  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fdgrib2            0804BFA2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fdgrib2            0804A827  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          B72E94D3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

fdgrib2 process finishes at commands on grib_get.f90

```
  [fortran] call tokenize_ws(lines(1),tokens,ntok)
   nb = index(tokens(1),'=')+1
   ne = len_trim(tokens(1))
   read(tokens(1)(nb:ne),*) longdate [/fortran]
```

I am not an expert fortran programmer so I am not sure how to deal with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

Added print statement to locate when the error comes up

> ```
>    call tokenize_ws(lines(1),tokens,ntok)
>    nb = index(tokens(1),'=')+1
>    ne = len_trim(tokens(1))
>
> print*,'P3'
> print *,lines(1)
> print *,tokens(1)
> print *,tokens(1)(nb:ne)
> ```
>
> read(tokens(1)(nb:ne),*) longdate
>
> print*,'P4'

and the output (pass through P3 but does not arrive to P4). 2014012000 is the right date and time of the input data file

```
 P3
 1.1:0:d=2014012000
 1.1:0:d=2014012000
 2014012000

forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
fdgrib2            080761C0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

**EDIT 2**

Code of subroutine tokenize_ws in tokenize.f90

```
subroutine tokenize_ws(str,tokens,ntok)

implicit none

integer :: ntok
character(len=*) :: str,tokens(*)
character(len=1) :: sep,tab

integer :: ntokmax=100,npt,nch,nc,ntbeg,ntend,n

! this routine "parses" character string str into different pieces
! or tokens by looking for  possible token separators (toks
! str contains nch characters.  the number of tokens identified is nto
! the character string tokens are stored in tokens.

! Modified 12/11/07: this version tokenizes by white space (spaces and tabs)
sep = char(32)
tab = char(9)

ntok=0
npt=1
nch=len_trim(str)
nc=1
do ntok=1,ntokmax
   do n=nc,nch
      if(str(n:n) /= sep .and. str(n:n) /= tab) then
         ntbeg=n
         goto 21
      endif
   enddo
   21 continue
   do n=ntbeg,nch
      if(str(n:n) == sep .or. str(n:n) == tab) then
         ntend=n-1
         goto 22
      endif
      if(n == nch) then
         ntend=n
         goto 22
      endif
   enddo
   22 continue
   tokens(ntok)=str(ntbeg:ntend)
   nc=ntend+1
   if(nc.ge.nch) goto 25
enddo

25 continue

return
end
```

**EDIT 3**

Added source code and input files (linux tar files)

http://ubuntuone.com/5tL2IO8OV5dBxhs18kt1WI

http://ubuntuone.com/1meYXbBuBt1Rxcx4ODMzVp

**EDIT 4**

Output of compile options -traceback -warn -check

[log file](http://ubuntuone.com/2hxOJkxYizNGfx9ieqxnMh)

and output of model run

> 2014012000
>
> ```
>        9          19 forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read Image              PC
> ```
>
> Routine            Line        Source              fdgrib2
>   080942C0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown fdgrib2
>   08092D14  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown fdgrib2
>   0806F822  grib_get_mod_mp_g         291  grib_get.f90 fdgrib2
>   08051CD0  MAIN__                    130  dgrib.f90 fdgrib2
>   0804A757  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown libc.so.6
>   B72CF4D3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

**EDIT 5**

After changing `read(tokens(1)(nb:ne),*) longdate` (chars 9 to 19) to `read(tokens(1)(nb:ne-1),*) (chars 9 to 18) longdate` it seems to properly read longdate, expected value was 2014012000. But then another error appears, as I post this info I'll continue looking for a solution. fdgrib2 is a "relatively old" read code for grib2 files but it worked and should still work, my fault. Thanks for your help.

```
print*,'P3'
print *,lines(1)
print *,tokens(1)
print *,tokens(1)(nb:ne)
print *,nb,ne
read(tokens(1)(nb:ne-1),*) longdate
print*,'P4'
print*,'ddd:', longdate

P3
 1.1:0:d=2014012000
 1.1:0:d=2014012000
 2014012000
          9          19
 P4
 ddd:  2014012000
 1--1.1:0:scan=0 input=WE:NS output=WE:SN:grid_template=0:winds(N/S):
--
 ppp0:           0         360         181 lat-lon             
 ppp0:  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
fdgrib2            08094350  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fdgrib2            08092DA4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
fdgrib2            0806D724  grib_get_mod_mp_g         219  grib_get.f90
fdgrib2            08051D20  MAIN__                    132  dgrib.f90
fdgrib2            0804A757  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          B72984D3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Comment: Since you are using the intel Fortran compiler, can you turn on backtrace by adding -traceback? This will help you understand what the program was doing and where it died. In general, the performance penalty of this flag is so small and its utility so large I ALWAYS run with it. Also, compile time and run time checks might help too: try adding -warn and -check to the compile and link flags.

Comment: Hi @zbeekman, I followed your advice and compiled again. There are more messages but I can't find any relevant information (at least I can't, maybe others will see). Logfile can be found at the URL in EDIT 4 in the question

Comment: Are you trying to use list-directed input for an internal read of slice `9:19` from a character variable ?  If so, consider how many characters there are in that slice, and how many there are in the number `2014012000`.

Comment: Hi @HighPerformanceMark That's what the program tries, I am not the developer. I have changed `nb,ne` to `nb,ne-1` as date runs from character 9 to 18. It seems to proper read longdate but ends in another error. You can see at this [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/244041/ifort.png)

Comment: I'm not going to chase your problems across the internet.  If you want me to look at the new error, post enough information here for me to have a good chance of diagnosing it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was easier this way. I'm gonna edit the question and add the info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Information added to the post, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This Q&A is getting too long to follow.  Either completely rewrite the question or ask another one.  Observe that your 'new' error is actually an occurrence of the old error at a different place in the input file. Its diagnosis and cure are likely to be the same as the diagnosis and cure for the previous occurrence.  Personally I think that your use of tokenisation and list-directed i/o is a mismatch and that you should use one or the other.  I note that you claim not to be a developer but as soon as you asked a question about the code you became a developer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You are right, I am forced to be a developer but I don't claim I am. I will try to follow the chain and try to correct the succesive errors. And yes, it's getting too long. I'm gonna close the question and come back with a new one in the next week, say maybe two, with a new rewritten one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The internal list directed read error means that there is a read statement, but instead of a file unit number, a variable is being used. Without being able to see line 219 in grib_get.f90 or 132 in dgrib.f90 along with the declarations of any variables being referenced, it is impossible to help you diagnose this. As @HighPerformanceMark noted, I would guess that the read statement in question is exhibiting a similar error to the one you fixed, but that is speculation. The off by one string length error makes me suspect some code is in C or someone is used to writing C.

Comment: @zbeekman Hi and thanks for answering. I could go on and compile by checking formats in read sentences but the final output was not running fine. My problem came from an old piece of software that was not optimised for Intel compiler, hence giving such error messages. Actually, a new version of the software has been uploaded and I could succesfully compile and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help. Finally I could succeed.

My problem came from an old piece of software that was not optimised for Intel compiler, hence giving such error messages when reading grib2 files (GRIB2 is a format used in meteorology). Actually, a new version of the software has been uploaded and I could succesfully compile and run.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done it already, then fix the cause of the warning raised by the compiler.  The snippet

```
ichar(tokens(1))
```

passes a character variable of length 20 to `ichar` which expects a variable of length 1.

I don't see how this could cause your later problems but it's generally a good idea to grasp at every straw when trying to fix mysterious bugs.

Comment: Yes, I commented on that it is irrelevant.

Comment: But if some nasty stack corruption occurs noone knows.

Comment: How should I fix that? I'm not an expert programmer.

Comment: `tokens(1)(1:1)` is a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Check the input files, and specifically the location the code is currently processing at the time of crash. There is some problem when reading longdate from the `tokens(1)(nb:ne)`, that are made from the lines(1). You can add some print statement to make it clearer:

```
    print *,lines(1)
    print *,tokens(1)
    print *,tokens(1)(nb:ne)
```

Also, don't worry about the warning. It is not a good piece of code, but it is in a print statement, so it just prints something not that well defined to the standard output.

Comment: I will try and let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: Please, take a look at the edited question with the print statements output @vladimir-f

Comment: How is `longdate` defined? I played with integer scalar and it works OK. Isn't it an array by any chance?

Comment: `integer :: nx,ny,nrec,iscan,longdate`

Comment: I am puzzled by this, just check if `nb` and `ne` have correct values, but it seems to be the case. I am trying it on my computer and it works OK for `nb = 9` and `ne = 19`.

Comment: Exactly, 9 and 19 are OK. I added the code for tokenize_ws in the question @vladimir-f Thanks for your time and help.Should I send the whole code for fdgrib2 and input grib files?

Comment: I don't know, I am out of ideas, maybe someone other will find out.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. At least it has focused the problem :-) In case you have spare time I uploaded two tar files with fdgrib, grib2 input files and f90 progs at [link](http://ubuntuone.com/1meYXbBuBt1Rxcx4ODMzVp) and [link](http://ubuntuone.com/5tL2IO8OV5dBxhs18kt1WI) @vladimir-f